_lsopenurlswithcompletionhandler() failed with error 54
I'm Getting this issue while installing the POSTGRES 14.14 via EDB tool.
Is there a way to fix it ? (I'm using MAC OS - M3)
I tried to install postgressql 14.14 via EDB tool.
Is this issue regarding a permission issue or something ?

Proceeding with step 3 directly should also work as mentioned by @Daniel Nathan. DId you try?

I had the same issue with macOS Sequoia 15.1
For latest MAC update to macOS Sequoia 15.1 seems to have problem with pgAdmin. For me this solution worked

Uninstalled existing postgres and downloaded latest postgres version
Upon installation of new version, uncheck the pgAdmin from items to be installed
After postgres installation completes, download pgAdmin from https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-macos/ and select latest release supported by Sequoia 15
Proceed with installation and it works fine not error is displayed

